# How to download/install pre-compiled Subversion binaries for Debian

Tags: linux, svn, unix, debian

Been trying to upgrade my subversion installation, but due to (what I believe) are limited rights (I'm using hosted Linux account), I'm not able to properly "./configure" and compile the source code (see posts [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189906/upgrade-subversion-143-to-152-on-debian-hosted-account) and [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274656/building-subversion-154-on-debian-could-not-find-library-containing-rsanew) if very interested)

So, I'm thinking if I could just download **pre-compiled binaries**, the just might solve my problems.  If you have better ideas - I'd love to hear that too!

NB: I'm not able to call **aptitude** or **apt-get install subversion** as suggested by [subversion.tigris.com](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#debian)

**I'm also interested in knowing how I would go about installing those pre-compiled binaries :)**

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing why this is being downvoted... who am I ticking off!? :þ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the binaries from the deb package for your architecture (which you can download from [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=subversion&exact=1)) using `dpkg-deb -x`.

So for example you can do this if you're on i386:

```
wget ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.5.4dfsg1-1_i386.deb
dpkg -x subversion_1.5.4dfsg1-1_i386.deb subversion
```

Of course you might have to do some tweaking to make it work. Extracting a package is not the same thing as installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Debian list of [SVN packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=subversion&exact=1), I would assume the [etch (stable)](http://packages.debian.org/etch/subversion) is the one you need.

Comment: But I'm looking for the 1.5.4 build... which is supposed to be a stable Subversion release but apparently the package is flagged as experimental

Comment: If you want 1.5.4, then you need the experimental package.

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189906/upgrade-subversion-143-to-152-on-debian-hosted-account#194115) thread on the same topic.

Comment: I'm a Windows user so I guess this is even harder for me!